# first() not working on the existing RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to import a csv file into the RDD format. When i use `.first()` command to get the first row of the rdd, it gives the error as mentioned below.

It seems the `.map` function makes the RDD into the pipelined RDD on which a command like `.first()` and `.count()` does not work. Is there any other way to work on this ?

```
import csv
import StringIO

def loadRecord(line):
    input = StringIO.StringIO(line)
    reader = csv.DictReader(input, fieldnames=["PassengerId","Survived","Pclass","Name","Sex","Age","SibSp","Parch","Ticket","Fare","Cabin","Embarked"])
    return reader.next()
input = sc.textFile("C:\Users\rohit.guglani\Documents/train.csv",4).map(loadRecord)

type(input)

pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD



input.first()
```

gives this error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-d93d15081c08> in <module>()
----> 1 input.first()

C:\spark-1.6.1\python\pyspark\rdd.pyc in first(self)
   1313         ValueError: RDD is empty
   1314         """
-> 1315         rs = self.take(1)
   1316         if rs:
   1317             return rs[0]

C:\spark-1.6.1\python\pyspark\rdd.pyc in take(self, num)
   1265         """
   1266         items = []
-> 1267         totalParts = self.getNumPartitions()
   1268         partsScanned = 0
   1269 

C:\spark-1.6.1\python\pyspark\rdd.pyc in getNumPartitions(self)
   2361 
   2362     def getNumPartitions(self):
-> 2363         return self._prev_jrdd.partitions().size()
   2364 
   2365     @property

C:\spark-1.6.1\python\lib\py4j-0.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    811         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    812         return_value = get_return_value(
--> 813             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
    814 
    815         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\spark-1.6.1\python\pyspark\sql\utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     43     def deco(*a, **kw):
     44         try:
---> 45             return f(*a, **kw)
     46         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     47             s = e.java_exception.toString()

C:\spark-1.6.1\python\lib\py4j-0.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    306                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    307                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 308                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    309             else:
    310                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o50.partitions.
ohit.guglani/Documents/train.csv
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The code works for me, but on a Linux platform. Check the path string you are passing to textFile so it either doesn't contain backslash characters or prefix the string with `r` to prevent Python to interpret the backslash character as being special.

Comment: Thanks Philippe. There was an issue with the backslash. I also figured that you cant run .first() on the pipelined RDDs but <rdd>.top(n) works on pipelined RDD.

Answer (score 0):

when working on Windows you should be careful while using `/`instead of `\`

```
input = sc.textFile("C:\Users\rohit.guglani\Documents\train.csv",4).map(loadRecord)
```